# How to display first menu item content with javascript that is hidding menu items until clicked

Tags: javascript

I have 3 images as menu items.  When you click on the image, a div with content below the images is displayed.  As you click each menu item, the content in the box is displayed.  I need the first menu item's content to display be default.  Right now all the menu items content is hidden.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have:

Html

```
<div class="dupImage img" data-menu="duplication"><img /></div>
<div class="repImage img" data-menu="replication"><img /></div>
<div class="shareImage img" data-menu="share"><img /></div>

<div class="menuitem" id="duplication">
    <h3>Create</h3>
  Some text here to describe create
</div>

<div class="menuitem" id="replication">
    <h3>Find Insights</h3>
  Some text here to describe Find Insights
</div>

<div class="menuitem" id="share">
    <h3>Share & Publish</h3>
  Some text here to describe Share & Publish
</div
```

>

Javascript

```
(function ($) {
var menu;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menuitem').hide();
    $('.img').click(function () {
        menu = $("#" + $(this).data("menu"));
        $(".menuitem:not(#" + menu.attr("id") + ")").fadeOut(0,function(){
             menu.fadeIn(800);
        });
    });   
});
})(jQuery);
```

Css:

```
.img {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #D4D4D4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
(function ($) {
var menu;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menuitem').not(':first').hide();
    $('.img').click(function () {
        menu = $("#" + $(this).data("menu"));
        $(".menuitem:not(#" + menu.attr("id") + ")").fadeOut(0,function(){
             menu.fadeIn(800);
        });
    });   
});
})(jQuery);
```

And here is the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3XptB/)